# Past Simple with "before" instead of Present Perfect

Tags: tenses

I have a problem with sentences in this context. I was using a pair of jeans but now they are not okay and I am not using them anymore so should I say:

A: These jeans were always okay before.

or

B: These jeans have been always okay before.

What about had been?

Answer (score 1):

Use the past perfect to speak about "past before a more recent past"; e.g.,
"My jeans had always been usable before they got torn."

In your example with "before", you can use past simple in the same way:
"My jeans were always good before they got torn."

As for your follow-up question, "What about the case when I am wearing them and I feel they are not good?" Example:

> Look, my jeans are too tight. They have always been okay (before). / They were always okay.

You would say, "They were always okay before [I washed them] *or* [I gained so much weight]." "They have been always okay before" is not idiomatic English.